# How to get unique record which is present in group 2 after comparing with group 1?

Tags: sql, sql-server

| Model | year |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 2009 |
| Apple | 2010 |
| HTC | 2010 |
| Motorola | 2009 |
| Motorola | 2010 |
| Nokia | 2009 |
| Nokia | 2010 |
| One Plus | 2009 |
| One Plus | 2010 |
| Samsung | 2009 |
| Samsung | 2010 |

how to get the model which is present in year 2010 but not in 2009.
result should be |HTC| 2010|

Comment: `HAVING` or `EXISTS` spring to mind. What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: The required logic is described too unprecise. What to do if further years appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with data as (
    select model from T where "year" = 2010
    except
    select model from T where "year" = 2009
)
select model, 2010 from data;
```

or

```
select model, 2010
from T
where "year" in (2009, 2010)
group by model
having min("year") = 2010;
```

or

```
select * from T
where "year" = 2010
and model not in (
    select model from T
    where "year" = 2009
        and model is not null
);
```

or

```
select * from T t1
where "year" = 2010
    and not exists (
        select 1 from T t2
        where t2.model = t1.model
            and t2."year" = 2009
    );
```

or

```
select t1.*
from T t1 left outer join T t2
    on t2.model = t1.model and t2."year" = 2009
where t1."year" = 2010 and t2.model is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT Model, year
FROM test 
where Model not in (select Model from test where year != 2010)
      and Model in (select Model from test where year = 2010)
```

This will return rows with Model that exist only once

Comment: thank you for the response however, this would also give me a result if there was a model xyz in 2009 as that is also count to 1.  I am looking for solution that results in something which is only in 2010 but not in 2009.